# Google Oauth2 provider not implemented

Tags: django, google-oauth, django-socialauth

I am working in **django 1.6**. My app requires social authentication, so I am using **django-social-auth** app. I am trying to list all the friends in my google account. I followed the steps as indicated in the url : http://c2journal.com/2013/01/24/social-logins-with-django/

Inorder to list all my friends I used **django-social-friends-finder**. I created a google api project and used the **client id** and **secret key** in **GOOGLE_OAUTH2_CLIENT_ID** and **GOOGLE_OAUTH2_CLIENT_SECRET** in my settings.py file. I gave my **localhost ip** for the **redirect_uri** parameter.

I successfully authenticated using my email, but could not list my friends list. When I debugged in the terminal error message is displaying as **'provider: %s is not implemented'**. I searched a lot but couldn't find a solution. Please help me out. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Never used `django-social-friends-finder`, but I guess it calls `https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/me/people/visible` at some point to retrieve your friends list. But to access that API you need to specify the correct scope, that way your access token has permissions for it. To do so in `django-social-auth` define this setting:

```
GOOGLE_OAUTH_EXTRA_SCOPE = [
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login'
]
```

Also this snippet shows how you can retrieve your friends list:

```
import requests

user = User.objects.get(...)
social = user.social_auth.get(provider='google-oauth2')
response = requests.get(
    'https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/me/people/visible',
    params={'access_token': social.extra_data['access_token']}
)
friends = response.json()['items']
```